# Free Monad in F# with generic output type

Tags: f#, monads, free-monad

I am trying to apply the free monad pattern as described in [F# for fun and profit](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/13-ways-of-looking-at-a-turtle-2/#way13) to implement data access (for Microsoft Azure Table Storage)

**Example**

Let's assume we have three database tables and three dao's Foo, Bar, Baz:

```
Foo          Bar          Baz

key | col    key | col    key | col
---------    ---------    ---------
foo |  1     bar |  2         |
```

I want to select Foo with key="foo" and Bar with key="bar" to insert a Baz with key="baz" and col=3

```
Select<Foo> ("foo", fun foo -> Done foo)
  >>= (fun foo -> Select<Bar> ("bar", fun bar -> Done bar)
    >>= (fun bar -> Insert<Baz> ((Baz ("baz", foo.col + bar.col), fun () -> Done ()))))
```

Within the interpreter function

- `Select` results in a function call that takes a `key : string` and returns an `obj`
- `Insert` results in a function call that takes an `obj` and returns `unit`

**Problem**

I defined two operations `Select` and `Insert` in addition to `Done` to terminate the computation:

```
type StoreOp<'T> =
  | Select of string * ('T -> StoreOp<'T>)
  | Insert of 'T * (unit -> StoreOp<'T>)
  | Done of 'T
```

In order to chain StoreOp's I am trying to implement the correct bind function:

```
let rec bindOp (f : 'T1 -> StoreOp<'T2>) (op : StoreOp<'T1>) : StoreOp<'T2> =
  match op with
  | Select (k, next) ->
      Select (k, fun v -> bindOp f (next v))
  | Insert (v, next) ->
      Insert (v, fun () -> bindOp f (next ()))
  | Done t ->
      f t

  let (>>=) = bindOp
```

However, the f# compiler correctly warns me that:

```
The type variable 'T1 has been constrained to be type 'T2
```

For this implementation of bindOp the type is fixed throughout the computation, so instead of:

```
Foo > Bar > unit
```

all I can express is:

```
Foo > Foo > Foo
```

How should I modify the definition of StoreOp and/or bindOp to work with different types throughout the computation?

Comment: I can point you to the exact reason for this error in your `bindOp` code, but the root reason is your `StoreOp` type. If you look at it closely, you'll see that it can only ever express chains of operations on the same type.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to avoid all these levels of indirection and do the simple CRUD stuff in something like a [Transaction Script](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/transactionScript.html)? That's similar to what Tomas Petricek describes in the last paragraph of his [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41668459/467754). See also [Why the free Monad isn't free](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U0lK0hnbc4U).

Comment: The current implementation is a simple set of imperative CRUD functions. Please see comment below for motivation.

Answer (score 5):

As Fyodor mentioned in the comments, the problem is with the type declaration. If you wanted to make it compile at the price of sacrificing type safety, you could use `obj` in two places - this at least shows where the problem is:

```
type StoreOp<'T> =
  | Select of string * (obj -> StoreOp<'T>)
  | Insert of obj * (unit -> StoreOp<'T>)
  | Done of 'T
```

I'm not entirely sure what the two operations are supposed to model - but I guess `Select` means you are reading something (with `string` key?) and `Insert` means that you are storing some value (and then continue with `unit`). So, here, the data you are storing/reading would be `obj`.

There are ways of making this type safe, but I think you'd get better answer if you explained what are you trying to achieve by using the monadic structure.

Without knowing more, I think using free monads will only make your code very messy and difficult to understand. F# is a *functional-first* language, which means that you can write data transformations in a nice functional style using immutable data types and use imperative programming to load your data and store your results. If you are working with table storage, why not just write the normal imperative code to read data from table storage, pass the results to a pure functional transformation and then store the results?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To answer your question: I am trying to separate pure and impure code as explained in [Purity in an impure language](http://blog.leifbattermann.de/2016/12/25/purity-in-an-impure-language-free-monad-tic-tac-toe-cqrs-event-souring/). You mentioned that there are ways to make "the obj solution" type safe. Could you share the approach you would take to do this?

Comment: I agree that separating pure and impure code is desirable, but free monad is a terrible way of doing that. In the end, the code will be impure anyway - what the free monad lets you do is to abstract away how exactly the impurity is handled - and I think there is no benefit in that. (You could argue that's useful for testing, but I think it just obscures the testing of the key part which you should be testing and that's the operations on the data.) If there is specific thing you want to achieve, then there is a better way to do that.

Comment: As for a type safe version, you'd end up with a type that statically tracks the types of all reads and writes such `M<Read<int,<Write<string,<Read<int, Return<unit>>>>>>>` An example project that uses this is: http://blumu.github.io/ResumableMonad/

Comment: Interesting, I'll give that a try. Disclaimer: Opinion, anecdotal. I had good experience with free monads in the past, however I did not encounter the need for generic output types so far. Testability is an aspect frequently mentioned in the literature. In addition I like the fact that implementation details, like using ``Option`` or ``Choice``, logging, or local state are neatly located soley in the interpreter function. Also the execution of impure code is pushed to the boundary of the execution of the application. Currently I am trying to compare a CRUD solution with a free monad solution.